# Vite dev proxy 'new URL(url, import.meta.url)'

Tags: cross-domain, worker, laravel-vite

Good day!

I have recently switched from laravel-max (webpack) to laravel-vite (vite).

Web page (index.php) is served from *php server* and *vite hmr* separately for js dev server.

I wanted to convert workers by workerize-loader to web worker modules in vite.
(I would like to use Typescript and imports.)

So, if you load worker as

```
const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.ts', import.meta.url), {type: 'module'})
```

it works fine after building.
However, the problem is, that site is served (**in dev**) from `https://localhost:8000` and  `new Worker(new URL('./worker.ts', import.meta.url), {type: 'module'})` resolves to `'https://localhost:5173/@fs/path-to/worker.ts?type=module&worker_file` and **Workers can be initiated only from same origin**.

I suspect I have three solutions:

1. Proxying in vite dev server: I could not configure out that
2. Importing worker through fetch/axios to Blob and create a worker from the Blob. However, then the worker cannot have import statements and Typescript.
3. (Appended) Remove vite hmr and use vite as webpack - each change compiles down to code that is requested by browser (dont know how to do with laravel-vite)

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am using Vue 3 composition-api, if it helps

Comment: @flydev, it is not a service worker

Comment: I will make you an example, but my best suggestion to avoid those sort of issue, is to use a **custom dns** for **local development**, eg, running your project under `https://mysite.localdev` where `.localdev` is the tld (it's just an example).  Cross origin will not be an issue anymore, and your development will be easier.